# Why i'm getting only one entry on Gmaps map?

Tags: channel-entries, google-maps, title

This is my code:

```
{exp:gmaps:init} 


{exp:gmaps:geocoding width='100%' height='100%' marker='yes' map_types='roadmap|terrain' map_type='Hybrid' scroll_wheel='yes' zoom_control='yes' pan_control='yes' map_type_control='no' scale_control='yes' street_view_control='yes' address_format='[city]' div_id='mymap'}
{address}
{exp:channel:entries channel='travels' disable='categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks' dynamic='off' cache='yes' refresh='512640' orderby='date' sort='asc'}
{scheda_del_viaggio orderby='city' sort="asc"}{city}|{/scheda_del_viaggio}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/address}
{marker:html}
{exp:channel:entries channel='travels' disable='categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks' dynamic='off' cache='yes' refresh='512640' orderby='date' sort='asc'}
{scheda_del_viaggio orderby='city' sort='asc'}
<h1 class="h3-like text-strong">[location]</h1>
<a href="{title_permalink={segment_1}}">
<span class="h3-like first-letter">{title} - {travel_check_in format="%d %F %Y"}</span>
</a>|
{/scheda_del_viaggio}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/marker:html}
{/exp:gmaps:geocoding}
```

I dont understand why I'm getting only one entry title for the channel 'travels' on my map..

Answer (score 1):

Only had a very very quick look at this one and admittedly being very very naughty haven't tried the code out but noticed that you have a cache set. Did you by any chance load the page when you only had the one entry and then tried again before the cache had refreshed perhaps? Just a quick thought though.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing dynamic="off" to dynamic="no"

Comment: Thank you Johnathan for your reply but changing dynamic='no' it makes no difference..

Comment: Yeah it won't because "off" is backwards compatible.